# Yii2 - getting sum of a column

Tags: yii2

I found this in the guide, but have no idea how to implement the same

`yii\db\Query::count();` returns the result of a COUNT query. Other
similar methods include `sum($q)`, `average($q)`, `max($q)`, `min($q)`, which
support the so-called aggregational data query. `$q` parameter is mandatory
for these methods and can be either the column name or expression.

Say for example I have a table name 'billing' with columns:

```
name     amount
charge1  110.00
charge2  510.00
Total -  620.00
```

How I implement using

```
yii\db\Query::sum('amount');
```

I have also  tried like

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT sum(amount) FROM billing");

yii\db\Query::sum($command);
```

but page generates error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first part of code you tried appears to be attempting to use Query Builder.  In this case, you must create an instance of a query, set the target table, and then compute the sum:

> Via Query Builder
>   (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html):

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())->from('billing');
$sum = $query->sum('amount');
echo $sum;
```

The second part of code you tried appears to be attempting to use Data Access Objects.  In this case, you can write raw SQL to query the database, but must use `queryOne()`, `queryAll()`, `queryColumn()`, or `queryScalar()` to execute the query.  `queryScalar()` is appropriate for an aggregate query such as this one.

> Via Data Access Objects
>   (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html):

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT sum(amount) FROM billing");
$sum = $command->queryScalar();
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works fine. but in the first solution I have to edit the line like `$sum = $query->sum('amount');` is it ok? if I use the code as it is I am getting the error - **Call to a member function sum() on a non-object**

Comment: Glad it works! You are correct about the variable name, I've updated the post.

Answer (score 24):

Within a model the sum could also be fetched with:

```
$this->find()->where(...)->sum('column');
```

Comment: It's clean and simple when you use the model itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can directly use yii query concept in Search Model

```
$this->find()->from('billing')->where(['column'=>value])->sum('amount');
```

OR

```
$this->find()->where(['column'=>value])->sum('amount');
```

Outside the Model (Billing is model name)

```
Billing::find()->where(['column'=>value])->sum('amount');
```

Comment: Like this can add function in search model and can be use in grid or somewhere else required.                                                                public function getTotalamount() {
        return $this->find()->from('billing')->where(['column'=>value])->sum('amount');
    }

Comment: billing is the model name

Answer (score 7):

i hope your model name is Billing

inside Billing model use

```
$this->find()->sum('amount');
```

in other models

```
Billing::find()->sum('amount');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$invocedAmt = ProjectMilestone::find()
                ->select(['sum(pm_amount) as pm_amount,count(pm_id) as pm_id'])
                ->where(['pm_p_id'=>$Project->p_id,'pm_est_id'=>$estimation->est_id,'pm_status'=>1])
                ->groupBy('pm_est_id')
                ->one();
```