# Yii2 Query does not return column sum

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have this code, example:

```
$rows = Category::find()
->select('id_category, SUM(p.comments * 10) AS num')
->leftJoin('post p', 'p.id = post_id')
->groupBy('id_category')
->one();
```

This exist: `$rows->id_category`
But this not exist: `$rows->num`

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852453/yii2-getting-sum-of-a-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a field named 'num' in your Category model otherwise you can't access to this value. add the public var $num this way

```
class Category extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public $num;

    /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
    public static function tableName()
```